# Expected value - you roll a d6 untill you get a first non-6, then you win $6^{n-1}$ dollars

Tags: probability, expected-value, geometric-distribution

Consider this probability excercise:

You roll a six-sided die. If you roll a six, you keep rolling until you roll a first non-six. Then you win $6^n$ dollars, where n is the amount of times you rolled a six before you failed.

It is clearly a geometric distribution. We have $n\sim Geo(\frac{5}{6})$. We have that $E(n)=\frac{6}{5}$. So $E(6^{n-1})=6^{\frac{1}{5}}$. Thus answer is $\sqrt[5]{6}$

However I saw this (clearly incorrect solution):

The probability that you lose in $n^{th}$ trial is $\frac{5}{6}\times \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n-1}$ and if you lose on the $n^{th}$ trial you get $6^{n-1}$ dollars. Thus the expected winning should be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5}{6}\times \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n-1}\times 6^{n-1}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5}{6}$, which diverges.

Now this obviously doesn't give the right answer, but I don't know where particularly this reasoning fails. I am not a statistician and what I suspect is wrong is that this formula (sum overvalues times the probability they occur) does not apply here, I do however wonder why.

Edit: I updated details fory solution. Turns out the other one was wrong, so the follow up question: what is wrong with the first solution?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: How did you get that the answer is $\sqrt[5]{6}$?

Comment: The probability of rolling $n$ 6s followed by a non 6 is ${1 \over 6^n} {5 \over 6}$ and the reward is $6^n$. Hence the expectation is ${5 \over 6} + {5 \over 6}+ ...$.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a finite-valued random variable having an "infinite" expectation; your answer seems correct.

Comment: This is similar to the St. Petersburg paradox.

Comment: A classic case: Toss a coin until it shows heads with a payout of two to the power of the tosses' count.  $$\mathsf E(2^T) =\sum_{t=1}^\infty 2^t/2^t$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expected value that does not converge, is the *correct answer*. This does happen.

$$\begin{align}n&\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(5/6)\\ \Pr(n\,{=}\,k) &= (5/6)(1/6)^k~\mathbf 1_{k\in[[0..\infty)]}\\\mathsf E(6^n) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty 6^k(5/6^{k+1})\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac 56\end{align}$$

Comment: If n follows geometric distribution, why doesn't it follow $E(6^n) = 6^{\frac{1}{p}}$?

Comment: @Zyx Because that is $6^{\mathsf E(n)}$, which is not the same thing.  For the same reason that $\mathsf E(n^2)\neq \mathsf E(n)^2$.